# Is there a way to make every bouton using a single code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For a school project, I'm coding a porfolio.
I want to use jQuery hide() and show() to have popups that appear after clicking on buttons.

Is there a way, with a single code, to make every HTML element with the `class="vignette"` and an `id="bouton1"` show a `div` with the same number in id (id=popup1).
I don't know if I'm clear, I'm a student in graphic design, and I'm not having a good time.

Comment: Yes that is possible, and if you post the code you have it would be easier to give you a good answer

Comment: id is supposed to be unique, it might cause you problems if not. But it would be `$("#bouton1.vignette").show()`. I wont guarantee that it works because of the id isn't unique.

Comment: Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can understand from your question, you want to show a modal whose ID is the same number as the button's ID?

You can use this same logic to work with your modal instead

```js
// This regex just gets the number part from the ID
const re = /bouton(\d+)/
$('button.vignette').click(e => {
    const res = re.exec(e.target.id)
    if(res) {
        // "popup" + res[1] gives the popup id
        $('#content').html("popup" + res[1])
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class = "vignette" id = "bouton1">B1</button>
<button class = "vignette" id = "bouton2">B1</button>
<button class = "vignette" id = "bouton3">B1</button>
<button class = "vignette" id = "bouton4">B1</button>
<div id = "content"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm string to do, thank you, I did not include my code because it's really messy at the moment as I am trying to make it look good in css at the same time, I should have said that my buttons aren't buttons, they are <article> that holds images. I have trouble integrating your code on my page and I think it is because of that, is there anyway to go around that?

Comment: I guess it should be `article.vignette` or `img.vignette` (whichever holds the vignette class) instead of `button.vignette` then.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function that will be added via `addEventListener`. Alternatively you can add an `onclick` attribute to the HTML elements whose click you want to handle.

```js
let activeDiv;

function myClick() {
    if (activeDiv) activeDiv.classList.add("invisible");
    (activeDiv = document.getElementById(this.id.replace("bouton", "popup"))).classList.remove("invisible");
}

let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("vignette");

for (let button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener("click", myClick);
}
```

```css
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="bouton1" class="vignette" value="First">
<input type="button" id="bouton2" class="vignette" value="Second">
<input type="button" id="bouton3" class="vignette" value="Third">
<input type="button" id="bouton4" class="vignette" value="Fourth">
<input type="button" id="bouton5" class="vignette" value="Fifth">
<input type="button" id="bouton6" class="vignette" value="Sixth">
<input type="button" id="bouton7" class="vignette" value="Seventh">
<input type="button" id="bouton8" class="vignette" value="Eigth">
<input type="button" id="bouton9" class="vignette" value="Ninth">
<div id="popup1" class="invisible">1</div>
<div id="popup2" class="invisible">2</div>
<div id="popup3" class="invisible">3</div>
<div id="popup4" class="invisible">4</div>
<div id="popup5" class="invisible">5</div>
<div id="popup6" class="invisible">6</div>
<div id="popup7" class="invisible">7</div>
<div id="popup8" class="invisible">8</div>
<div id="popup9" class="invisible">9</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

suppose you have 10 buttons with class `vignette` then you code would be:

```
$.each( "button.vignette", function( i, obj) {
  $(obj).attr( "id", i ).on('click',function(){
    $('#popup'+i).toggle();
  });
});
```

You can replace `toggle()` function with your code as desired.